# Unittesting MVC controller

Tags: model-view-controller, unit-testing, controller, automapper, castle

Im trying to learn MVC combined with IoC and DI. In my project I also use Castle, Automapper, NHibernate, NHibernateIntegration.

Thanks to the excellent example "ToBeSeen" app by Kozmic I think I have the solution pretty much set up now. But now I want to unittest basic save operation at the controller method level. I just dont get how to go about this. I expect my problem is pretty simple but Im a novice at this and any help is appreciated.

I have a dossiercontroller like this:

```
    [Authorize]
    [Transactional]
    public class DossierController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IRepository repository;
        private readonly IMappingEngine mappingEngine;
        private readonly ILogger logger;

        public DossierController(IRepository repository, IMappingEngine mappingEngine, ILogger logger)
        {
            this.repository = repository;
            this.mappingEngine = mappingEngine;
            this.logger = logger;
        }
```

As you can see it needs a repostitory, mappingengine and logger. As I understand all this is configured and wired up at runtime.

Next I have a controller method that is used to save a dossier:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Dossier")]
        [Transaction]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [AcceptParameter(Name = "button", Value = "save")]
        public ActionResult Dossier_Save(string button, DossierModel dossierModel, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(dossierModel);

            Dossier dossier = mappingEngine.Map<DossierModel, Dossier>(dossierModel);

            repository.Save(dossier);

            return View();
        }
```

Here I just want to automap the dossiermodel into a dossier and save it using the repository.

Now I want to unit test this using Nunit. I dont want to mock anything, I want a real persistence test from the controller level. For this I have to create a new dossiercontroller and pass in the correct arguments. Now Im lost. How do I create and configure the arguments so they work exactly like in the web application. For instance: How do I create a correctly configured Automapper in a Unittest? How do I create a correctly configured repository? Should I use a container?

Any help, especcialy a code example is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mock anything, you will need to instantiate concrete versions of the services required by the constructor of your controller.

e.g.

```
IRepository repository = GetRepository();
IMappingEngine mappingEngine = GetMappingEngine();
ILogger logger = GetLogger();
DossierController controller = new DossierController(repository, mappingEngine, logger);
ActionResult rsult = controller.Save(...etc...);
```

As to how you are to configure and instantiate these, you will essentially need to do this in exactly the same way that your MVC app is doing this.

If you are unsure where in your MVC app these are being configured, I'd suggest that the first place to look is in the IoC configuration and work backword from there.

Comment: Thanks! Im new to this, do you have an example of mocking pls? kind regards, Hein

Comment: Mocking means that you basically set-up a fake instance of your interface, and set it up to return canned responses.  You will need to use a library for mocking services - I use Rhino Mocks - though I know Moq is popular. Have a look at [link](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks) for a basic example.

Comment: So if I get it right Mocking means I will not access the actual database. But then how can I unit test to controller to see if it actually persists anything if I call it? Or should I not call the actual Save method in the controller? Now I call repository.save directly from the controller.Is this smart? Or not?

Comment: Unit testing is about isolating parts of your system into units, and testing them independently of other units.  So you want to test that your controller calls your repository layer correctly.  You use a fake 'mocked' repository for this - so the tests for your controller don't rely on a concrete repository to pass.  You will need to test your concrete repository separately in a different set of tests.  If  your tests confirm that the controller behaves as it should, and the concrete repository behaves as it should, you can be confident that the controller will save things to the DB.